# Checksum value for GCP ops-agent installation script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ops-agent

I'm using this reference to install Ops-Agent on my server: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation#install-latest-version

I'd like to do a checksum verification of the downloaded script before running it, but I'm unable to find the checksum value of this script in GCP pages. Does anyone have any information or link references to get this checksum value that I can verify my downloaded file against?